# Printing Permissions for Guest Users

Tags: permissions, printing, windows-server-2008, active-directory

I have a Windows Active Directory Domain Network that has a print server with 3 printers attached to it. I do not want users to print from computers or devices that are not joined to the active directory domain. All users (regardless of whether or not if they are a domain user) will be on the same subnet (because there is only one Cisco Router (1921) and 2 un-managed switches (instant plug and play).

EDIT

I do not want users to:

1. Print from a device or computer that has not joined the domain corp.domain.com
2. Successfully add or manage any domain printers using Wizards or TCP/IP (regardless of the OS).

How can I do this?

Comment: If you allow non-domain joined machines onto your network and you only have SoHo equipment then you can't do what you're asking because you've no control features on your LAN such as VLANs, 802.1X or ACLs to only allow domain joined computers access to a separate print network that could be allowed access to trusted computers only...

Comment: The best solution would be to upgrade your equipment, create VLANs with ACLs and 802.1X so that only your domain joined computers can get onto the VLAN that has ACLs to access your printer VLAN. Kind of like a staff/visitors lounge where only the coffee machine can be operated by the staff... additionally, you'd have a separate network/VLAN for guests that can only access, say, the Internet. They can connect but can't access your printer VLAN.

Comment: I've just re-read, are the printers physically connected directly to the print server? Or are they connected to your LAN and then managed by the print server?

Comment: @BigChris: They are connected directly to the LAN and then managed by the print server

Comment: In that case, you're going to find it very hard to limit access to the printers with your current setup, as they'll be able to be discovered by anyone on your LAN because your network is, essentially, open.